# Edit Sharepoint excel C#

Tags: c#, excel, selenium-webdriver, sharepoint

I have to edit an excel on sharepoint platform. My Microsoft account needs an OTP verification code to access and I don't have the privileges to create an app password. What I tried to do is login with my microsoft account using Selenium and then access to excel by web request. the problem is that I got

> "System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (405)
> Method Not Allowed.'"

when I call

> response = request.GetResponse();

because of I dont know How to use cookies got by Selenium to access to the excel... This is my Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string base32Secret = "xxxxxxx";
            var secret = Base32Encoding.ToBytes(base32Secret);

            var totp = new Totp(secret);
            var code = totp.ComputeTotp();

            Console.WriteLine(code);

            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://myaccount.microsoft.com/");

            // Username
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("i0116")));
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("i0116")).SendKeys("xxxxx");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("idSIButton9")).Click();

            // Password
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("i0118")));
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("i0118")).SendKeys("xxxxxxx");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("idSIButton9")).Click();

            // OTP
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("idTxtBx_SAOTCC_OTC")));
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("idTxtBx_SAOTCC_OTC")).SendKeys(code);
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("idSubmit_SAOTCC_Continue")).Click();

            // Stay connected
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("idSIButton9")));
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("idSIButton9")).Click();


            PublishWorkbook("C:\\test\\exceltest.xlsx", "https://teamsite.xxxxxx.com/:x:/s/test597/xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx_xxxxxx?e=xxxxx");
        }

        static void PublishWorkbook(string LocalPath, string SharePointPath)
        {
            WebResponse response = null;

            try
            {
                // Create a PUT Web request to upload the file.
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(SharePointPath);

                request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; // Here??
                request.Method = "PUT";

                // Allocate a 1K buffer to transfer the file contents.
                // The buffer size can be adjusted as needed depending on
                // the number and size of files being uploaded.
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                // Write the contents of the local file to the
                // request stream.
                using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                using (FileStream fsWorkbook = File.Open(LocalPath,
                    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    int i = fsWorkbook.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    while (i > 0)
                    {
                        stream.Write(buffer, 0, i);
                        i = fsWorkbook.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    }
                }

                // Make the PUT request.
                response = request.GetResponse();
            }
            finally
            {
                response.Close();
            }
        }
```

thank you in advance guys!

Comment: I don‘t know anything about Selenium and Sharepoint Access but maybe it is sufficient for you to sync the OneDrive folder to a local pc and edit it from there.

Comment: You are not the man I deserve, but the one I need

Comment: Haha, you‘re welcome :)